# Play Framework for comprehension type mismatch

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework

I am using Play Framework version 2.6.11, when building the Application controller, I get the **error**:

```
Expression of type IndexedSeq[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] doesn't 
conform to expected type Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)]
```

in the code:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.libs.oauth.{ConsumerKey, RequestToken}
import play.api.mvc.{ BaseController,  ControllerComponents}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class Application @Inject() (config: Configuration, c: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {
  def tweets = Action.async {
    val credentials : Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = for {
      apiKey <- config.get[String]("twitter.apiKey")
      apiSecret <- config.get[String]("twitter.apiSecret")
      token <- config.get[String]("twitter.token")
      tokenSecret <- config.get[String]("twitter.tokenSecret")
    } yield (
      ConsumerKey(apiKey.toString, apiSecret.toString),
      RequestToken(token.toString, tokenSecret.toString)
    )

    // use credentials to invoke twitter API and return Ok
    Future.successful { Ok } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that the method `get` in `Configuration` will return a `String` and not an `Option[String]`, so you are flatMapping over a String.

If your configuration keys are optional you should use the method `getOptional`, so you will end up to have the tuple if all the four configuration keys are present

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.libs.oauth.{ConsumerKey, RequestToken}
import play.api.mvc.{ BaseController,  ControllerComponents}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class Application @Inject() (config: Configuration, c: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {
  def tweets = Action.async {
    val credentials : Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = for {
      apiKey <- config.getOptional[String]("twitter.apiKey")
      apiSecret <- config.getOptional[String]("twitter.apiSecret")
      token <- config.getOptional[String]("twitter.token")
      tokenSecret <- config.getOptional[String]("twitter.tokenSecret")
    } yield (
      ConsumerKey(apiKey.toString, apiSecret.toString),
      RequestToken(token.toString, tokenSecret.toString)
    )

    // use credentials to invoke twitter API and return Ok
    Future.successful { Ok } 
  }    
}
```

[Play Api Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.10/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration@getOptional[A](path:String)(implicitloader:play.api.ConfigLoader[A]):Option[A])